# Use of comparative degree when no comparison is being done

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

I have studied in my academics that we can use comparative degree when comparison is being done. But today I came across use of comparative degree without any comparison. Is it correct to use comparative degree when there is no comparison?

Also, if possible can anyone give the instances where it can be used without comparison? The sentence I came across was

> Its revolutionary features, futuristic design and host of exciting applications will turn you everyday into a *smarter* celebration.

(Here it refers to any brand name.)

Comment: The so-called non-comparative comparative is extremely common in advertising speak. By the way, that doesn't seem like natural English. It looks like it was written by a non-native speaker. Not to mention "everyday" instead of "every day". "Everyday" of course means "not special or interesting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the comparison is implicit. Smarter compares the future to the present. For example,

> This course will help you become a **better** person.