# Is it grammatically incorrect to use comparative forms without an explicit object of comparison and without progression over time?

Tags: comparatives

In colloquial English, comparative forms can be used ungrammatically. However, suppose I want to write in a strictly grammatical fashion.

I know that some comparative forms can be used with an implicit comparison to the same object over time:

> Its revolutionary features, futuristic design and host of exciting
>   applications will turn you everyday into a smarter celebration.

or

> This course will help you become a better person.

That was addressed in:

[Use of comparative degree when no comparison is being done](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90854/use-of-comparative-degree-when-no-comparison-is-being-done)

There, "smarter" makes sense because the you of today is being compared to the you of yesterday.

I typically use comparatives with "than" or "as."

Colloquially, I might say:

> Taller athletes run faster.

And by that, I probably mean:

> Taller-than-usual athletes run faster than average athletes.

However, to the best of my knowledge, it is necessary to say "taller-than-usual" or "taller-than-average."

Is there any grammar book or style guide that would endorse "Taller athletes run faster" as grammatical?

Comment: I don't understand "...will turn you everyday into a smarter celebration". How can *you* be a *celebration*?

Comment: Can't find  a reference, but it's perfectly standard English (not colloquial) to speak of _older people, taller athletes_ and the like.

Comment: Your "rule" does not exist. There is nothing wrong with *taller athletes run faster*.